# How do I control the size of large images in css?

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing

newb here with silly question...I have a header with a logo image inside it that I think has very large dimensions (1200px I think) but I need it to not show up so huge. I've tried to resize it in CSS but nothing is happening, what am I doing wrong? I'd like to be able to resize it without adding dimensions into the HTML.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: .5rem;
}

.header {
  background: #3f6660;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 0.75rem solid #2e4945
}

.logo img {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.nav-list,
.nav-item,
.product-list,
.product-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background: #8BDF83;
  border: .2rem solid #FEFFFE;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem 0rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 150ms;
}

.nav-link:focus,
.nav-link:hover {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://i.natgeofe.com/n/f0dccaca-174b-48a5-b944-9bcddf913645/01-cat-questions-nationalgeographic_1228126.jpg" alt="logo" />
    </div>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Products</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've moved your code into a snippet for readability and so that it can be executed.  Do you think you could change the image `src` to point to an actual image with similar dimensions as your logo (or a copy of the logo itself) for the purpose of recreating/reproducing this issue?

Comment: I've just grabbed a largeish image off google just as an example
-- sorry realizing this image isn't big enough...I'll find another

Comment: Since it's a logo I'm assuming you want it to fill the width so maybe `max-width: 100%;`  in your `.logo img` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: When I grab an image of the web it resizes perfectly fine regardless of images original dimensions. But when I add an image from a folder it blows up to its huge size....why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the desire width and height value to the below css class

```
.logo img {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;    
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: .5rem;
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I add the width and height values